# Chapter number starts at 2 not 1

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters

How can I start my chapter from "Chapter 2" instead of "Chapter 1".

I am preparing LaTeX document for each chapter. when I put `\chapter{Introduction}`, it produces "Chapter 1" Introduction. However I want it to be "chapter 2" Introduction instead.

Answer (score 66):

You need to specify `\setcounter{chapter}{1}` before your chapter command for the introduction. This is due to the fact that the `\chapter{}` command increments the *chapter* counter of one before printing any output.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following output:

[image: Output]

**EDIT** An alternative proposed by Gonzalo Medina is to use instead `\stepcounter{chapter}` instead of `\setcounter{chapter}{1}` for the same output.

Comment: @SeanAllred, I tried to make it clearer in my answer. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: :-) [filler text]

Comment: It works! Cool! I appreciate your time.