# Suppress Chapter Number and Chapter Title Completely

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I am working on the layout of my PhD thesis. For designing purpose, I would like to suppress the chapter number and chapter title completely without disturbing section numbering (Figure below).

[image]

Well, I managed to remove the chapter title easily by `\chapter{}`. Although with `\chapter*{}` chapter number disappears, it affects the section numbers. Is there any way to achieve this **without disturbing section numbering**?

Please note that the Table of Content is not important.

Thank you in advance. :)

my (sample) working code is as below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\centering\huge\bfseries}{\LARGE\centering\MakeUppercase\thechapter\thispagestyle{empty}}{1pc}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{1}

%\chapter{Ch one}
\chapter*{}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{{\Large Abstract}}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2-3]

\mbox{}
\vfill

\noindent This chapter is based on:\newline

\noindent Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text .

\hspace{0pt}
\pagebreak


\section{section 1}
\lipsum[2-5]

\section{section 2}
\lipsum[2-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or alternatively something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124326/chapter-number-starts-at-2-not-1 with `section` instead of `chapter`.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the chapter numbers *and*  titles? Can't you leave out the `\chapter` commands in that case completely? Or perhaps using the `article` class instead is even more appropriate

Comment: @siracusa: Following on your comment, I solved the question by resetting section numbers in combination with skipping `\chapter`. Thanks :)