# How to use Latex to write a report starting from chapter 9 instead of chapter 1?

Tags: article, report

I need to write only one chapter using Latex. I tried to use a document class **report** because I need the equations to be numbered as: (9.1), (9.2), ... etc. But I need to start from chapter 9 and I do not know how to make it start from chapter 9 instead of chapter 1. Is there any option I can use?

Comment: Just write `\setcounter{chapter}{8}` in the preamble.

Comment: Related (but not quite a duplicate): [Getting section numbering to start at 0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107470/82917).

Comment: @campa Would you please post your first comment as an answer to the question, so it can be officially answered? This is IMHO an easy solution that solves the issue, but unless there is a "real" answer to the question, it will have to be abandoned, which doesn't make sense. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkusG. I haven't written an answer because I'm fairly sure this is a duplicate, but I haven't found time to look for it yet.

Comment: @campa That makes a lot of sense. Maybe this one? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124326/chapter-number-starts-at-2-not-1 It uses chapter, but is essentially the same.

Comment: @MarkusG. Yep, that looks good!

Comment: @campa  it worked thanks

Comment: @Markus G Thank you.